# how to change up button to icon and preventing activity from being destroyed when intent to a new activity and calling back from back button

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I am new to the Android platform.
I have some design issues and need your valuable suggestion.

1. Currently, I have an up button that is used as a button to open the navigation drawer layout. How to change this up button to some icon.
2. My expandable list view calls a new activity. let say main activity calls category activity but as soon as I press back button main activity is destroyed and recreated.

I will post some picture and code if necessary.

![Main Activity with expandable list view in drawer layout][1]

Answer (score 0):

do it in On Create

```
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("About Us");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
```

use the id of icon which you want to paste.

```
    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.mosque_dailog);
```

Comment: Does not works for me. Icon do not display. Is their anything related to size and  format of icon.\

Answer (score 0):

use this:

1. create an imageview object
2. `upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_icon);
               upArrow.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);`
3. and then set it to
   `getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);`

wherever you need

Hope this helps

Comment: my screen blinks whenever i click icon

Comment: is the code working? this is actually a work around..which is the version of the os you are using?

Comment: Linux i don't know the version. I am new to linux as well. But my android platform is 5.1. Is their anything to concern about version.

Comment: yes ..cause i tested it on jellybean and my screen doesnt blink